# How to resolve the issue of ValueError: could not convert string to float: when my every column is having more than 10 unique character values?

Tags: python, string, training-data

I know this question has been asked 100 times but i can't find a specific issue. My dataset is very huge with 5 columns (minimum) and every column consist of more than 20 unique values in string type. I have applied `Label encoder` in my training model but if if it keeps on storing unique values then it won't give accurate result and if i use `OneHotEncoder` then it will increase my datasets size and will face `memory issue`.

I am working on building a Decision tree classifier, i read about it that it supports character type values but i am getting `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` so i thought of changing it into integer but again facing another issue of huge storage

```
print(mydataset)

     col1   col2   col3   col4  col5
1    abc    def     ghi   jkl   mno
2    pqr    stu     vwx   yza   bcd  
3    efg    hig     jkl   mnl   opq
.    .      .       .     .     .
.    .      .       .     .     .
.    .      .       .     .     .
1000 rfg    dyj     okl   ohj   wed
```

Above i have given a rough idea of my dataset. In actual i have 40,000 fields in my dataset.
Is there any other solution where i can also deal with huge memory utilization in converting my field values to int and train my model directly?

Thanks in advance